# Converting from DocumentTermMatrix to Quanteda dfm

Tags: r, nlp, quanteda

I'm trying to run a Naive Bayes Classifier but getting the following error when I try to use a dtm in place of a dfm:

```
Error in UseMethod("textmodel_NB") : 
no applicable method for 'textmodel_NB' applied to an object of class 
"c('matrix', 'character')"
```

I can't seem to find a method of converting my dtm to a dfm. The reason I created a dtm originally and not a dfm is I've made a dictionary of words that I want to be included and I could only find a method of including them in a tm dtm, not in a quanteda dfm:

```
dtm.train.nb <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus.train, control=list(dictionary = fivefreq))
```

Comment: You should try this within **quanteda**. You can create the dfm using `dfm(your_texts, select = your_dictionary)` and it will then work nicely with `textmodel_nb()`.

Comment: @KenBenoit that's exactly what I was looking for! Couldn't seem to find anything online about the select argument